# por que return me devuelve undefined al iterar un array con un for each

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de iterar el array products con un for each pero me devuelve com resultado el return undefined y no se a que se debe esto.
pues el forEach si itera las veces que debería y el template si esta definido y tiene los datos correctos

```
 let values = Object.values(venta);
const products = values.filter(product => typeof product === 'object')

products.forEach((product) => {
    let templete = `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="name">
                <p>${product.name}x${product.quantity}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <p>$${product.price}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    console.log(templete);

    return templete

});
```

no entiendo por que retorna undefined si al mostrarlo en consola me muestra todo bien

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Para empezar forEach no devuelve nada. Y aunque devolviera algo, no lo estás intentando guardar en ningún sitio

Comment: estoy en otra parte de la app creando unas cajas que actúan como registros de un lapso de un dia en de un historial de ventas. la info de los registros la obtengo de un objeto que tiene entre otras cosas los prouductos que son los que quiero listar y se supone que cada uno de esos productos se construye con un "templete" que es a varible con ese fragmento de html.

Comment: pero ya lo e solucionado no sabia que un forEach no retornaba cosas. lo e sacado y tambien inicie la variable template fuera y dentro del foreach le fui sumando el resultado de cada iteracion.

Comment: et values = Object.values(venta);
    const products = values.filter(product => typeof product === 'object')
    let templete
    products.forEach((product) => {
        templete += `
            <div class="row">
                <div class="name">
                    <p>${product.name}x${product.quantity}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <p>$${product.price}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    });
   
    return templete

Comment: gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que forEach no devuelve nada, para lo que quieres hacer las opciones correctas son [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) o [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce):

Con map puedes obtener un array de strings

```
let htmlArray = products.map((product) => {
    let templete = `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="name">
                <p>${product.name}x${product.quantity}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <p>$${product.price}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    console.log(templete);

    return templete
});
```

Con reduce obtendrías un único string con todos los divs:

```
let html = products.reduce((string, product) => {
    let templete = `${string}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="name">
                <p>${product.name}x${product.quantity}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                <p>$${product.price}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    console.log(templete);

    return templete

});
```

Comment: muchas gracias Pablo, no tenia ni idea de  esos métodos.  gracias!!!