# forEach Javascript - ¿Cómo funciona?

Tags: javascript

Estoy testeando una function Javascript, en las pruebas siempre entra a la condición y hace el `console.log()`, me funciona de esta forma:

```
function getByName(name)
{
    let result = {};
    FAKE_DATA.forEach(element => {

        if (element.title === name) {
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@');
            result = element;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

pero esta otra:

```
function getByName(name)
{
    let result = {};
    FAKE_DATA.forEach(element => {

        if (element.title === name) {
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@');
            return element; // dudo del comportamiento de esta línea
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

me devuelve siempre el objeto vacío, ¿por qué?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [por que return me devuelve undefined al iterar un array con un for each](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286878/por-que-return-me-devuelve-undefined-al-iterar-un-array-con-un-for-each)

Comment: @x3k_js Estoy con la duda de si marcar como duplicada (la respuesta la di yo, ni me acordaba ya) o no, porque aquí la pregunta la entiendo ligeramente diferente: ¿Qué hace internamente forEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a hacer una implementación sencilla del método forEach para que veas cómo funciona (una versión más completa sería [ésta, de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach#Polyfill):

```js
function paraCadaUno(fn, array) {
  if (array === undefined) {
   array = this;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   fn(array[i], i, array);
  }
}

Array.prototype.forEach2 = paraCadaUno;

let test = [0, 2, 4, 6];

let suma1 = i => { 
  console.log('sumamos uno a', i);
  return i + 1;
}

let resultado = test.forEach2(suma1);
console.log(resultado);
```

Como puedes ver, el método sólo se encarga de ejecutar la función que le pases como parámetro para cada elemento del array, nada más. Cualquier resultado de la función es ignorado.

Si lo que estás buscando es un elemento o varios que cumplan una condición, o quieres obtener una transformación de los datos, tienes otros métodos disponibles:

```js
let test = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

//quiero todos los pares, filtramos los que cumplen la condición
let pares = test.filter(a => a % 2 === 0);

console.log('Pares', pares.toString());

//quiero el primer par, sólamente
let primerPar=test.find( a => a % 2 === 0);
console.log('Primer par', primerPar);

//quiero los números multiplicados por 2:
let duplicados = test.map(a => a * 2);
console.log('Duplicados', duplicados.toString());

//quiero sumar todos los elementos
let total= test.reduce((acumulador, b) => acumulador + b);
console.log('Suman', total)
```

Comment: Buena, sobretodo el **resumen de los principales métodos para trabajar con arrays**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes en el segundo ejemplo es que `forEach` **no devuelve nunca nada(undefined).**

La sintaxis de [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) es la siguiente:

```
arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg]);
```

Como verás callback es una función anónima que recibe estos tres paremetros:

1. Valor actual del array.
2. Index actual del array.
3. El array completo que estas recorriendo.

En tu caso te conviene mejor utilizar algo tipo [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) que funciona exactamente como `forEach` con la única diferencia es que devuelve el valor que cumpla una condición o **`undefined`** en caso contrario

Ejemplo:

```js
let personas = [{name:'Persona1', id:1}, {name:'Persona2', id:2}];

let persona = personas.find(persona => persona.id === 1)
console.log(persona)
```

Answer (score 0):

.forEach retorna `undefined`:
[Valor de retorn de .forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach#Valor_de_retorno)

```js
let returnValue=[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(e=>{
    console.log(e);
});
console.log(returnValue);
```

El valor vació, es de la variable `result`, en la que ningun momento has "rellenado", cuando haces un "map" `let nuevoArray=array.map();` estarías recogiendo el valor retornado por el map, en tu caso no estas recogiendo el que retorna el `forEach` (algo normal), si lo hicieras verías el `undefined`:

```js
function getByName(name)
{
    let result = {};
    result=[{"title":"titulo"},{"title":"example"},{"title":"prueba"}].forEach(element => {
        if (element.title === name) {
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@');
            return element; // el return no hace nada, por defecto retorna `undefined`
        }
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(getByName("example"));
```

El `return` dentro del metodo `forEach` no te sacara de tu función `getByName` si no que retornara el valor del `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya te han explicado bastante como funciona el `forEach`, solo quería aclarar que otra forma de verlo es que el `forEach` lo único que hace es ejecutar un callback por cada elemento. `.forEach(callback)`, `.map`, entre otras, hace algo como `.map(return callback)`. Un ejemplo parecido a como funcionaría `forEach` pero con un `for`:

```js
function evalua(e) {
  return e + 1;
}

const a = function(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    evalua(i);//<-- solo ejecuta, no hace return
  }
}

console.log(a());//<-- siempre va a ser undefined
```

`forEach` es similar a `for`, la gran diferencia es que el `forEach` **siempre** itera sobre todos los elementos y en orden. Esto quiere decir que no podemos modificar el `indice` y no podemos tampoco hacer un `break`.